# Case statement for number of array elements greater than 0

Tags: bash

How can I use a bash case statement for determining whether the number of array elements greater than `0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  wildcard `*`:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(1 2 3)

case ${#arr[@]} in
  0)
    echo "array is empty"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "array length > 0"
    ;;
esac
```